# Determine $k$ to make this a pdf

Tags: probability

I have to find $k$.I tried everything.
  The pdf is
         $$f(x,y,z)=\begin{cases}k(xy-xyz) &0<x,y,z<1, \;\;x+y<1 \\0 & \text{elsewhere} \end{cases}$$

Let $y<1-x$.
I got $k=48$ I believe the book was $k=144$ 
$$f(x,y,z)= \int_0^1 \int^{1-x}_0 \int_0^1 xy-xyz \;dx\;dy\;dz$$
It is problem with my limits I tried math studio And can’t get $k=144$ ugh
Can someone help me to determine $k$ to make it a pdf if I am wrong

Comment: Please consider learning [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: What is the support of $x,y,$ and $z$?

Comment: You have the right idea that you want the integral over all the variables to equal $1$.  I can't read your expression to see if you got the right one, nor do you show how you got from the integral to the answer for $k$.  Without that, we can't tell what went wrong.

Comment: What is the Mathias for a definitite. Integral

Comment: That is all that is given.   A similar solved. Integral from http://www.ams.sunysb.edu/~jsbm/courses/311/examples-joint-pdfs-sol.pdf gives k=24

Comment: The support is shown in the integral